# CoreData Fatal Error: Illegally Mutated the NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am getting a strange `CoreData` error every once in a while:

> CoreData: FATAL ERROR: The persistent cache of section information
>   does not match the current configuration.  You have illegally mutated
>   the NSFetchedResultsController's fetch request, its predicate, or its
>   sort descriptor without either disabling caching or using
>   +deleteCacheWithName:

I found another Stackoverflow thread saying to set the cache to nil, which I have done, but that did not fix the error:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

The error is coming from my `getData` method, which returns an array of the fetched results.  I call this method often, because I want to check the count, and update a tableView:

```
+ (NSArray *)getData {

    // Fetch Data
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[[AppDelegate instance] fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return [[AppDelegate instance].fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];

}//end
```

Why would this be causing an error? Is this an incorrect way to get an updated array of objects from the `fetchedResultsController`?

Comment: Is it possible to log `cacheName` when the error occurs and check you are definitely fulfilling the requirements.  If you are I can't see anything you've done wrong according to the restrictions stated in the documentation.

Comment: Why do I even need caching? I doubt my store will ever contain more than 10 objects, EVER.

Comment: You don't. The error message said the error was caused because you were using caching.  You said you weren't, it was just a suggestion to double check that you weren't using it inadvertently.